# laravel restful контроллер

Tags: php, laravel

Есть такое задание "С ​​использованием ​​фреймворка ​​Laravel ​​реализовать ​​RESTful ​контроллер, ​к​оторый ​​при обращении ​к​ ​​нему ​с​ ​`​Accept: ​t​ext/html` ​​отдавал ​​бы ​​данные ​​из ​​шаблона, ​​а ​​при ​​обращении по ​т​ому ​​же ​​маршруту ​с​ ​`​Accept: ​​application/json`, ​​отдавал ​​бы ​к​орректный ​​RESTful ​​ответ, согласно ​​RFC". Как сделать RESTful ​контроллер понятно, а вот дальше ничего не понятно, что означает Accept: ​t​ext/html?

Answer (score 3):

В HTTP-заголовке `Accept` клиентского запроса к серверу перечисляются типы данных (MIME), которые клиент может обработать и ожидает получить.

То есть вам нужно проанализировать содержимое этого заголовка в запросе, которое можно получить следующим образом:

```
$accept = request()->headers->get('accept');
```

и если он содержит или равен `text/html` (`request()->acceptsHtml()`), то вернуть HTML вариант страницы:

```
return view('page_template');
```

а если он содержит или равен `​​application/json` (`request()->acceptsJson()`), то вернуть данные в формате JSON:

```
return response()->json($page_data);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, поделитесь источниками информации

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Http/Request.html

Comment: набираюсь смелости спросить, а как собственно проверить правильно ли будет работать, каким образом можно сформировать нужный нам http заголовок, если у фреймворке идет по схеме роутер-контролер-виев

Comment: либо попробуйте использовать какие-нибудь плагины, например:https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/modify-headers/ либо   реализуйте самостоятельно, с помощью curl, например.

Comment: да Вы прямо кладезь знаний :)

Comment: Если вы пользуетесь Хромом, для проверки запросов рекомендую расширение Advanced REST Client (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

Работает как отдельное приложение. Позволяет запоминать типичные запросы (что удобно для отладки). Позволяет задавать любые заголовки и детально анализировать ответ.